# Flutter Firebase Auth doesn't work from Google Play

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-signin

I've firebase auth services in my flutter app. It's working on emulator & real device (while debug). But when i publish it on google play neither alpha test or release version it doesn't work.

**Main.dart**

```
        StreamProvider(
      create: (context) => context.read<AuthenticationService>().authStateChanges,
    )
```

**AuthService**

```
  final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth;
  AuthenticationService(this._firebaseAuth);
  AccessToken accessToken;
  Stream<User> get authStateChanges => _firebaseAuth.idTokenChanges();
```

**SignedIn Method in AuthService**

```
  Future<String> signIn({String email, String password}) async {
    try {
      await _firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
      String uid = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid;

      return "Signed in";
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      return e.message;
    }
  }
```

**Login.dart**

```
  var login = await context.read<AuthenticationService>().signIn(email: mailController.text, password: sifreController.text);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be that you forgot to put the Google Play fingerprint into your Firebase App configuration.

If the Google Play fingerprint are not present on your app, there is no way for the user to connect to Firebase services.

You can find your Google play fingerprint into the Setup -> App Signing menu.
See the picture below

[image]

You should then add them in the android settings of your firebase app.

[image]

Comment: I've signed app (i guess i cannot publish without this step also), and in this page i see some keys

- app signing keys
*md5
*sha1
*sha256
-upload key certificate
*md5
*sha1
*sha256

idk how can i use them. but there is some keys

Comment: @EmreTufekci You should copy those keys in Android settings of your Firebase app.
I edited my post so you can see where to add the keys.

Comment: I were typing this answer, then you edited. While waiting you i figure out. Thank you so much, it was good hint for me :)

"@BLKKKBVSIK's answer is correct but i need to add more, i've added debug sha1 to firebase but it's not enough.

Go to @BLKKKBVSIK's shared screen copy SHA-1, then go to firebase console - android page add fingerprint and add that SHA-1 also. Then it worked."